# Terminology about ramification

Tags: class-field-theory, number-fields

Let $K$ be a totally real (finite) number field. Let $S$ be a finite set of places of $K$ containing the primes above a prime number $p$. Let $K_S$ be the maximal abelian extension unramified outside $S$. Let $S_\infty$ the set of infinite places of $K$.

I have noticed the following terminology that is confusing me. In some articles (e.g., Colmez $\S1.2$  and Serre $\S2.1$) immediately claim that $K_S$ contains all the $p^n$-th roots of unity, for all $n\ge1$. This is clear if $S$ contains $S_\infty$. But, if $S$ does not contain any place in $S_\infty$, then $K_S$ is unramified at infinity, and is totally real, hence can't contain this roots of unity.

On the other hand, in articles by Ribet, for example, it is always mentioned if $S$ contains $S_\infty$ or not, thus there is no confusion.

**Is it standard to assume that $S$ contains the infinite places, or one simply has to understand this from the context?**

The other possibility is that I'm not understanding something here. Sorry if this is the case, I'm not fluent in class field theory.

**References:**

Colmez, Pierre.
[*Fonctions L p-adiques.*](http://www.numdam.org/item/SB_1998-1999__41__21_0/) 
Séminaire Bourbaki, Vol. 1998/99.
Astérisque No. 266 (2000), Exp. No. 851, 3, 21–58.

Serre, Jean-Pierre. *Sur le résidu de la fonction zêta p-adique d'un corps de nombres.* 
C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. A-B 287 (1978), no. 4, A183–A188.

Comment: When $S$ is a finite set of places that does not mean it must contain $S_\infty$. Yet often in practice it does contain $S_\infty$ and this restriction should be explicitly stated when it occurs. Are you sure you're not overlooking some convention earlier in a paper that would imply the sets $S$ in the paper will always contain $S_\infty$? Please give some examples of papers where you think the author (say Serre) is forgetting to say $S \supset S_\infty$.

Comment: @KConrad I'll put the links in my question.

Comment: Please put actual article references in the post, not just links. When I click on the first link, I am sent to Google Books and it tells me in Spanish that I've reached my page limit.

Comment: @KConrad Sorry, I hope now is ok.

Comment: Ramification at the infinite places has its own definition, so when $K=\mathbf{Q}$ and $S$ is a finite set of prime numbers, some authors may implicitly consider that $\mathbf{Q}_S$ is the maximal abelian extension of $\mathbf{Q}$ unramified at each finite prime $q \not\in S$. So things may depend whether $S$ is a set of primes or a set of places. I agree that it should be said explicitly though.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault I'm aware of ramification at infinite places. For example, Serre talks about places, and that's exactly what confusses me. I know it's a detail, but I want to understand this correctly.

Comment: @EFinat-S You're right, in Serre 2.1 it seems the assumption $S \supset S_\infty$ is missing. I am not familiar enough with the literature to tell whether some authors leave ramification at infinity undefined, which would explain this.